# Error in extracting line using bat file

Tags: shell, batch-file, window

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in (myfile) do (
  set line=%%f
  call :processToken
  )
  goto :eof

:processToken

  for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %%a in (%line%) do (
  echo Got one token: %%a
  set line=%%b
  )
  if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
  goto :eof
```

In my text file I have lines like

```
"test a","test b","testdim"
"Line 2", "test d","testdin"
```

so when i see `for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %%a in (%line%) do (` with ECHO ON, %line% is showing as `"test a" "test b" "testdim"`.

I dont know why commas are missing but I need those commas so that I can use `"delims=,"` to get these values out of each line.

Comment: If you want help to parse this reliably then show us what is in the myfile and explain what you want to get in the outfile.

Comment: I am assuming that there is a `"` before `test d` in line 2.

Comment: myfile.txt is text file which contains following lines                "s test1","test b","stest1"                                         
"s test2","test d","stest2"                                                         So out of each line I want to extract first and third string like  "s test1" and "stest1"

Answer (score 2):

try this, added some double quotes:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in (file) do (
  set "line=%%f"
  call :processToken
  )
  goto :eof

:processToken
  ECHO "%line%"

  for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %%a in ("%line%") do (
    echo Got one token: "%%a"
    set "line=%%b"
    )
  if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken

  goto :eof
```

Comment: A little overboard - the added quotes in the `for..%%a...` partially cure the problem, but the second data line contains unbalanced quotes - `FOR` doesn't know which quotes are which and considers it imparsible. (sorry...)   String-processing like this in batch is limited - probably better using a tool designed for the job. Finally, I'd suggest that the `if not "%line%"` is better written as `if defined line` - but moot if your data or processing produced unbalanced quotes...

Comment: text parsing, better with `grep` or [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Comment: @PeterWright - Unbalanced quotes are easily solved with delayed expansion `... in ("!line!") ...`, and also adding delayed expansion toggling if data may contain `!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in (myfile) do (
   set line=%%f
   call :processToken
)
goto :eof

:processToken

for %%a in (%line%) do (
   echo Got one token: %%a
)
goto :eof
```